# format date based on format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, datetime

I have a date variable like:

```
var date_value = new Date(
  parseInt(date.year()),
  parseInt(date.month()) - 1,
  parseInt(date.day()));

// date_value = Date 2016-07-24T21:00:00.000Z
```

I want to format that date into many formats. Is there is any built-in function in JavaScript to format that date into any format I want in the convention of Python  Example: `(%m%d%Y),(%d%m%Y),("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")`? I used the `$.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy 00:00:00', date_value)` but it doesn't fit my needs.

Comment: Try http://momentjs.com/

Comment: i tried ! moment(date_value).format("%m/%d/%Y") but the value what not what i want the output is something like %0/%1/%Y

Answer (score -1):

There is not built-in functionality to format dates. You need to use an external library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Comment: i tried ! moment(date_value).format("%m/%d/%Y") but the value what not what i want the output is something like %0/%1/%Y

Comment: @MostafaMohamed: The page I linked explains how moment.js format strings are supposed to look like.

Answer (score -1):

```js
date_value = moment().year(year).month(month).date(day);
// or
date_value = moment(date);

date_value.format("M/D/Y HH:mm:ss");
```

Use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Comment: i tried ! moment(date_value).format("%m/%d/%Y") but the value what not what i want the output is something like %0/%1/%Y

Comment: try without "%", like in my answer ```format("M/D/Y")```